# $|f'|=0$ in $\mathbb C$ implies $f$ is constant, for $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ holomorphic.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives

My proof is this:

Let $f=u+iv$. We have $|f'|=0$, then $|u_x^2+v_x^2|\le |u_x|^2+|v_x|^2=0\Rightarrow u_x=0=v_x$. 
So $f'=u_x+iv_x=0$. As $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb C$, **Cauchy–Riemann equations** are true for $f$: $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$.

Taking the equation $f'=u_x+iv_x=v_y+iv_x=0$. Subtracting both equations: $u_x-v_y=0$. As we had $u_x=0$, then $v_y=0$.

Taking the same equation again: $f'=u_x+iv_x=u_x-iu_y=0$. Subtracting again: $i(u_x-u_y)=0\Rightarrow u_x=u_y=0$.

As we have all partials $u_x=u_y=v_x=v_y=0$, then $f$ is constant.

*Do you think my proof is ok?* Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: More conceptual if $\gamma(t)$ is any curve the $f(\gamma(t))$ has zero derivative and so by then real case $f$ is constant along that curve, and since its true for all curves, $f$ is constant.

Comment: If you have that holomorphic $\implies$ analytic then you can just use the power series of $f$.